Scholarly opinion on wifes right to intimacy
In Islam, there are some opinions regarding women's rights of intimacy. These are.
It should occur according to the need of wife and ability of husband
Husband should agree to intimacy once every four months
The third one is that instead of four months it should be four days.
Which scholarly opinion is more common
